# Intrinsic Camera Matrix after image rectification

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a fisheye camera which I already calibrated correctly with the provided calibration functions by OpenCV. Therefore, I got a 3x3 Intrinsic Camera Matrix K and vector with distortion parameters.

Using the last 2 I can rectify the input image with the functions `estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify` and `initUndistortRectifyMap` to obtain 2 transformation maps which I later use as input to the function `remap`. As output I get an undistorted image where parallel lines are maintained.

My questions are basically...

- Can I continue using the K intrinsic matrix I got from calibration in conjunction with the undistorted image?
- Has the intrinsic matrix K somehow changed due to the undistortion? In case this is true then how could I calculate the new K?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you computed intrinsics and distortion coefficients at the same time, you can keep K as it is. If you performed both steps independently, you should create new intrinsics with the indistorted images (and fix the distortion coefficients durin calibration). If you want to change the intrinsics, e.g. to get a bigger image (sometimes undistortion crops away image parts), you can specifiy the new intrinsics during initUndistortRectifyMap  however you like to.

Comment: @Micka I performed the calibration with the file /opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration.cpp . I got intrinsics and distortions at the same time as you pointed out. 

Can the new instrinsics matrix from estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify (computed to get a bigger image as you suggested) be used for Homography computation? Or is it valid only for the initUndistortRectifyMap operation?

Comment: it should be valid for the remapped (undistorted) image

Answer (score 2):

As @micka pointed out in the comments, after calibrating the cameras and undistorting the image, I can continue using the new camera matrix K outputted by `estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify`. This answers my 2 previous questions.

Comment: Whatever you set the  `newCameraMatrix` parameter to for `initUndistortRectifyMap` will be the K that is for the undistorted image. If you leave this parameter empty, then the principal point may be different than you want.